# Get dm-verity status (Corrupted or Verified) on Android using veritysetup

Tags: android, device-mapper

I'm trying to get dm-verity status from adb shell using veritysetup, but all the devices I'm passing result in:
`# cryptsetup 1.3.1 processing "./veritysetup --debug --verbose status /dev/device-mapper"`
`# Running command status.`
`# Initialising device-mapper backend library.`
`# Detected kernel Linux 3.10.49-gd004f33-dirty aarch64.`
`# dm version   OF   [16384]`
`# dm versions   OF   [16384]`
`# Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support disabled.`
`/dev/mapper: opendir failed: No such file or directory`
`Device /dev/device-mapper not found`
`# Releasing device-mapper backend.`
`# crypt_status: 0`
`Command failed with code 22: Invalid argument`

I'm trying it with: `/dev/dm-0, /dev/device-mapper, /system and /dev/block/mmcblk0p30` - all result with the same error.

The command line is:
`$ veritysetup --debug --verbose status /dev/block/mmcblk0p30`

What am I doing wrong?